# Web.py Session Data Disappears in Production

Tags: python, session, web.py

First of all, production means running with `web.config.debug = False`. So the suggested hook from the documentation does not help (also tested).
So my Login Script saves three variables to the session. When I access them within the function they are set they return the expected value.

```
                print session.get("privilege") # Return 0
                print logged() # Return 0
                session.login = 1
                session.privilege = ident['privilege']
                session.userid = ident['id']
                render = create_render(session.get('privilege'))
                print session.get("privilege") # Returns 1 <- as exprected
                print logged() # Returns True as expected
                raise web.seeother('/next')
```

In the next class all values are set to 0 again. 
Any ideas? I use git and even rolling back to an earlier (working) version did not help. This behaviour suddenly appeared. Only change i remember to do to the system (OSX Mavericks) is installing cliclick.

Comment: Could you give a more complete and simple example?

Comment: Does the user of application have permission to write sessions on the server? Did you see the session created at any time already?

Comment: Yes the session is created in the sessions folder. The app.py has 777 chmod.

Answer (score 0):

You should save session. Assuming that `session` is `web.ctx.session` then you should use `session.save()` before raise `web.seeother('/next')`